# Porting Wordpress widget plugin to Blogger gadget: admin interface, global settings?

Tags: wordpress, porting, blogger, opensocial, google-gadget

I'm attempting to port a Wordpress widget plugin to a Blogger gadget, and finding them extremely different worlds.  What the WP widget does is:

1. In the admin interface (provided by the widget object's `form()` method), it displays a list of the posts in the blog for the blog owner to select from, saving this as a widget setting.
2. In the widget display (provided by the widget object's `widget()` method), it displays some content linked to the post that was selected.

This seems to be bizarrely difficult behavior to replicate in a Google Gadget.  The questions I wind up having are:

1. As far as I can tell, Blogger barely has a concept of an admin interface, and certainly none that would manage widgets.  It seems like I need to deploy admin and user functionality through the same gadget display; am I correct about this?
2. I can get at a list of blog posts easily enough, but how in the world do I create a setting that's global to the widget instance instead of specific to the user viewing it?  I get the vague impression that that may be possible through OpenSocial in some way, but damned if I can figure out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you already checked the links: https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/gadgets/gadgets_for_blogger and https://developers.google.com/gadgets/docs/basic ?
They should have enough info for the item no 1.

**Please note:** With recent addition of dynamic views it seems like you need to hack stuff in order to make your gadget work when dynamic views are enabled (see [this article](http://blogger-hints-and-tips.blogspot.com/2012/01/adding-gadgets-to-dynamic-view.html)). Perhaps they'll improve that in the future but the last blogger gadget announcement related to dynamic views was in feb 2012 [dynamic-views-update-3-gadgets](http://buzz.blogger.com/2012/02/dynamic-views-update-3-gadgets.html).

For the item no 2, I am not sure either. Maybe they'll add that in the future.